# Remove moment.js from transitive dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, source-maps

Using source-map-explorer I can see that multiple libraries import their own moment.js library. My application itself also imports moment.js. Here is a snippet: [image: Snippet of source-map-explorer] Moment.js is imported 4 times in total. Is there way to remove this? I use IgnorePlugin to remove the locale at least.

Comment: can you share your webpack.config.js file, also which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove them during bundling by using the webpack alias feature:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'moment': path.resolve(path.join(paths.appNodeModules, 'moment'))
    }
}
```

Where paths.appNodeModules is the path to the 'node_modules' folder. This will makes sure every require('moment') actually uses the moment in your own node_modules folder.